# php array key index why show random

Tags: php

in php why array key index shows random (day value)

```
function getCustomHour($totals) {
    $startMonth = date("Y/m/", $this->startDate);
    $endMonth = date("Y/m/", $this->endDate);
    $data = array();
    $maxCount = array();
    if (empty($totals)) {
        return $data;
    }
    foreach ($totals as $testData) {
        $today = $testData['day'];
        $count = $testData['count'];
        if (empty($maxCount[$today]) || $count > $maxCount[$today]) {
            $maxCount[$today] = $count;
            if ($today < 10) {
                $data[$today]["Day"] = $endMonth . "0" . $today;
            } else {
                $data[$today]["Day"] = $startMonth . $today;
            }
            $data[$today]['Hour'] = $testData['hour'];
            $data[$today]['Count'] = $testData['count'];
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
    return $data;
}

Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Day] => 2019/03/03
            [Hour] => 23
            [Count] => 9
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Day] => 2019/03/04
            [Hour] => 23
            [Count] => 10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Day] => 2019/03/05
            [Hour] => 23
            [Count] => 6
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Day] => 2019/03/07
            [Hour] => 23
            [Count] => 5
        )

)
```

instead of 0,1,2,3 why it's show 3,4,5,7

i don't know what's the problem

i didn't use **rand** function but i can't able to this

what is the problem on this? how to show this 0,1,2

i don't know what's the problem

how to fix this ?

Comment: Where **exactly** should `0,1,2,3` be shown and why? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you are providing the key `$today` to `$data` which may not start with `0`.

What you can do is: Use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on `$data`

Before returning the `$data` reset your keys.

So that your keys will start from `0` to `1,2,3,...`

```
$data = array_values($data);
```

> array_values
>
> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7) array_values — Return all the values of an array
>
> Description ¶
>
> array_values ( array $array ) : array array_values() returns all the
>   values from the array and indexes the array numerically.